# Shifting list circularly python

Tags: python

Im having troubles implementing what i have so far into creating a true definition program.

```
def left():
    listL = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    k=4
    right = listL[k::]
    left = listL[:k:]
    print(right + left)


def right():
    listL = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    k=len(listL)-4
    right = listL[k::]
    left = listL[:k:]
    print(right + left)
```

My code claculates where to recreate the original listL based on moving left or right by k, in this case 4. However my practice problem asks...

```
Given a list of N numbers, write a function to shift the numbers circularly by some integer k (where k < N). The function should take the list and k as arguments and return the shifted list. 
a) Write a function that assumes the shifting is to the left. It should not print anything. 
b) Write a function that takes a third argument that specifies shifting left or right. It should not print anything. Perform whatever error-checking you consider necessary. 
c) Write a main() function that calls the above functions. It should print the lists both before and after shifting. Perform whatever error-checking you consider necessary.
```

i have satisfied part A. but im confused as to how i would build part B and C to fully replicate the problems question.

Solution sample run:

```
Sample run 
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
original list:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
shifted by 4, to the left: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3]
shifted by 4, to the right: [6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Any suggestions on how i should go about solving part b and c would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You need the function to take in input

Comment: If you're slicing with a step size of 1 (as you are here), you can skip the second colon in the slice notation. `right = listL[k:]; left = listL[:k]`. Also, negative indexes are allowed in list indexing and slicing. They count from the right starting with the last element at index `-1`, so your `right` function could do `k = -4` and it will just work.

Comment: You should create a _new_ question for your java question. Otherwise the answers here will look very confusing to others using the site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think this will work for the OP because it sounds like a CS course assignment, but for anybody else looking for the solution, just use:

```
from collections import deque

d = deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
d.rotate(3)  # to the right
d.rotate(-3)  # back to the left
```

---

*edit

Following up on your comment (from the [deque docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects)):

> Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is
>   pronounced “deck” and is short for “double-ended queue”). Deques
>   support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either
>   side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in
>   either direction.
>
> Though list objects support similar operations, they are optimized for
>   fast fixed-length operations and incur O(n) memory movement costs for
>   pop(0) and insert(0, v) operations which change both the size and
>   position of the underlying data representation.

Comment: very true, this is much more simplified so thank you! My class has not yet gone over deque. If you dont mind me asking, what is deque purpose because i just looked it up and it mentioned using the pop method which i am aware of already.

Answer (score 5):

Check this out:

```
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

circular shift by 4:

```
>>> b = a[4::] + a[:4:]
>>> b
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

and in a two functions format:

```
def shiftLbyn(arr, n=0):
    return arr[n::] + arr[:n:]

def shiftRbyn(arr, n=0):
    return arr[n:len(arr):] + arr[0:n:]
```

calling them:

```
print shiftLbyn([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3)
print shiftRbyn([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 4)
```

will give the output:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: ah yes! The function format is much better and cleaned up so much more so than mine. Thank you!

Comment: This works great but can you explain what [4::] [:4:] is doing?

Comment: @bretcj7 I can, but I believe that for you would be the best try on your own. Let me know if you don't figure it by tomorrow

Comment: Yes thank you i did find out the reason!

    `a[start:end] # items start through end-1`
    `a[start:]    # items start through the rest of the array`
    `a[:end]      # items from the beginning through end-1`
    `a[:]         # a copy of the whole array`
    `a[start:end:step] # start through not past end, by step`

Comment: @bretcj7, that's great! :) you may edit the answer if you want!

Comment: this is cool but how are you checking overflow? like if i put something greater than the length

Answer (score 2):

First change your functions to take parameters and return the result. eg

```
def left(listL, k):
    right = listL[k::]
    left = listL[:k:]
    return right + left # is this the usual meaning of left and right?

# This is how you call the function
print(left([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4))
```

Now if you notice that `left` and `right` have the same last 3 lines. You can combine them like this

```
def shift(listL, k, direction):
    if direction == "right":
        k = len(listL) - k
    right = listL[k::]
    left = listL[:k:]
    return right + left
```

I guess `main` would be something like this

```
def main(listL):
    print(listL)
    print(shift(listL, 4, "left"))
    print(shift(listL, 4, "right"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! i truly was looking for how i was to break down main() to work with the instructions to satisfy the problem using only def functions!